# How to add dynamic multiple text field in reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, dynamic

I would like to know how to add dynamic text fields in reactjs,

On clicking `add, delete` button in a row, adds and deletes the dynamic row which works,

But for the field `value`, has `+ and x` icon indicates add and deleting the dynamic value textfield.
this part of it was not working and got stuck.

here is my codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/embed/strange-hawking-k7nfh

Answer (score 0):

Issue I can see is you were using push method to add the new value , but .push method returns length of the array and not the new array. Rather use the concat method .You need to update your addtextareaHandler method as below :

```
addtextareaHandler = (row) => {

    var newArray = [...this.state.additionalFields]
    newArray[row.id].value = row.value.concat("");
    this.setState({
      additionalFields: newArray
    })
  }
```

For delete , you need to make change in the dynamicTable component as below to get the index of the value you are deleting

```
<td key={`tableview-td-${rowId}-${index}`}>
            <div style={contentareastyle}>
                {row[column.dataFieldId].map((datevalue,i) => {
                    return (
                        <div className="text-content" key= {`tableview-td-${rowId}-${index}`}>
                            <input type="text" value={datevalue} className="inputfield" readOnly />
                            <button className="btn-primary btntext" type="button" onClick={() => this.props.addtextarea(row)}>+</button>
                            <button className="btn-primary btntext" type="button" onClick={() => this.props.deletetextarea(row,i)}>x</button>
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        </td>
```

and update deletetextareaHandler as below:

```
deletetextareaHandler = (row,index) => {
    var newArray = [...this.state.additionalFields];
    newArray[row.id].value.splice(index,1);
    this.setState({ additionalFields: newArray });
  };
```

Create a method to handle the value change like

```
handleValueChange = (event,row,i) => {
    var newArray = [...this.state.additionalFields];
    newArray[row.id].value[i] = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ additionalFields: newArray });
  }
```

Add this to Dynamic Table tag in home component:

```
handleValueChange ={this.handleValueChange}
```

Change to be done in Dynamic Table component. Add onChange event in input tag.

```
<div className="text-content" key={`tableview-td-${rowId}-${index}`}>
                            <input type="text" value={datevalue} className="inputfield" onChange={(event) => this.props.handleValueChange(event,row,i)}/>
                            <button className="btn-primary btntext" type="button" onClick={() => this.props.addtextarea(row)}>+</button>
                            <button className="btn-primary btntext" type="button" onClick={() => this.props.deletetextarea(row,i)}>x</button>
                        </div>
```

Working solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-neumann-ov2wj?file=/src/home.js

Comment: thanks a lot, but when i enter the input textfield in value, not able to since i removed readOnly also

Comment: @codecat , you have to do event binding <input onChange = {this.handleEvent} /> like this .

Comment: @ Harmandeep Singh Kalsi thanks for reply, got stuck can you please https://codesandbox.io/embed/heuristic-https-uthuo

Comment: @codecat , where are you stuck , could you please elaborate the issue?

Comment: handling event on the input field, can you please help

Comment: You are using same handleInputChange , but I suggested to create a new method handleValueChange

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220784/discussion-between-harmandeep-singh-kalsi-and-codecat).

Comment: Here is the working solution https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-neumann-ov2wj?file=/src/home.js

Comment: thanks a lot for help, this scenario: click on add button, will add new row, enter key(eg sample), then enter value(eg test), click plus icon doesnot add row,

Comment: can you please help

Comment: when i add new row by clicking add button, enter the key textfield and enter the value textfield, click on + icon does not add row . can you please help

Comment: tested the code in codesandbox.io, if you click around the button, you get error `Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'value')`